# Bucket selector in sub aggregation or cardinality aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have this query

```
GET /my_index3/_search 
{
"size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "num1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "num1.keyword",
        "order" : { "_count" : "desc" }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_of_distinct_suffix": {
          "cardinality" :{
             "field" : "suffix.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filter_count": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                   "the_doc_count": "_count"
                },
                "script": "params.doc_count == 2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
          "key" : "1563866656878888",
          "doc_count" : 42,
          "count_of_distinct_suffix" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "1563866656871111",
          "doc_count" : 40,
          "count_of_distinct_suffix" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "1563867854325555",
          "doc_count" : 36,
          "count_of_distinct_suffix" : {
            "value" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "1563867854323333",
          "doc_count" : 12,
          "count_of_distinct_suffix" : {
            "value" : 1
          }
        },
```

I want to see only the results which have "count_of_distinct_suffix" : { "value" : 2 }

I'm thinking about bucket selector aggregation but it's impossible to add it into the cardinality aggs...

```
         "aggs": {
        "my_filter": {
           "bucket_selector": {
              "buckets_path": {
                 "the_doc_count": "_count"
              },
              "script": "params.doc_count == 2"
           }
        }
     }
```

It gives me the following `error: Aggregator [count_of_distinct_suffix] of type [cardinality] cannot accept sub-aggregations`

Do you guys have any idea to solve it?

Thank you very much for any help in advance !!

Comment: At what place are you adding the bucket selector aggs? Please add the complete query.

Comment: Sorry, I edited question and added complete query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add the `bucket_selector` aggs as a sub aggregation of `cardinality` aggs. Instead you should add it parallel to it as below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "num1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "num1.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_of_distinct_suffix": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "suffix.keyword"
          }
        },
        "my_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "the_doc_count": "count_of_distinct_suffix"
            },
            "script": "params.the_doc_count == 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see! Thank you very much, apparently I was lost in brackets :))

Comment: do you have any idea how to show the same result but only if the cardinality of two suffix happens within 72 hours?

Comment: Please post a separate question for the same.